# Traer a primer plano aplicación en c sharp

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en c# para escritorio. La aplicación utiliza un timer para chequear una base de datos. Si existen cambios en una tabla en concreto, disparo un proceso y, lo que necesito, es que la aplicación, si no está en primer plano, se ponga en primer plano. ¿como se puede hacer esto?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que vas a tener que usar las `api de windows` para poner en primer plano a la aplicacion, evalua algo como esto

```
private static class User32
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    internal static readonly IntPtr InvalidHandleValue = IntPtr.Zero;
    internal const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
}
public void Activate()
{
    Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    IntPtr hWnd = currentProcess.MainWindowHandle;
    if (hWnd != User32.InvalidHandleValue)
    {
        User32.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        User32.ShowWindow(hWnd, User32.SW_MAXIMIZE);
    }
}
```

[¿Cuál es la manera “correcta” de llevar una aplicación de Windows Forms al primer plano?](https://vike.io/es/602582/)

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!!